# How to apply EventLog on .NET platforms

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, .net-4.8

I created a plugin for logging on .NET Core class library and I would like it to be used by all my .NET apps when I tried to consume it on Windows Form .NET Framework it throws an exception

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I am using EventLog from System.Diagnostics.EventLog for logging on the event viewer

```
using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
{
    if (EventLog.SourceExists(eventSource))
    {
        eventLog.Source = eventSource;
        switch (logParameters.Type)
        {
            case LogType.Error:
                eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                break;
            case LogType.Warning:
                eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                break;
            case LogType.Information:
                eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Log Type doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Event Source doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create .NET standard rather .NET core.

Comment: I already used .NET standard but the same thing happens.